# Why does configuration state change cause listview in fragment to disappear but not textview

Tags: android

I have the problem that my list view inside my fragment will disappear when

- I change the screen orientation
- minimize the app into the background

*Interestingly, the text view does not disappear....*

Here is my fragment layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentBookmarks">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello world"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewMovies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/divider_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I solved the disappearing list view problem by adding the following code inside the activity tag inside my manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|keyboard"
```

My question is why does the list view disappear but the text view does not?

Comment: Are u setting some value to textview in fragment?

Comment: yeah it says hello world

Comment: that you set the text in xml. Can u set some value inside fragment programatically and test?

Comment: yes I have a custom cursor adapter that adapts to the list view

Comment: No Can u please set the text of textview inside your fragment. I mean do tv.setText("Test"); in onCreateView or where you are loading listview there, and test?

Comment: I have to move the text view to the `list_item` layout that is adapted to each entry in the list by the adapter, so I have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Because textview is already implemented onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.

By adding this line to manifest android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|keyboard", your activity wont be restarted with those config changes, so your listview wont disappear.

Refer to the following link: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState